# Insert the pickerInput in the DT of the shiny and can save the options

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I'm using shiny to create a **datatable** for our lab for sharing paper.
I'm distributing the app to my colleagues via a free deployment on **shinyapps.io**.
In order to be able to **update** the content of the datatable **between different users**, so I introduced `.rds`
Now I want to set one of the columns as a `selectInput` to allow others to rate it, or add tags, or whatever.

Here's my progress so far.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(rcrossref)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("input_name", "name", value = ""),
      textInput("input_count", "count", value = ""),
      actionButton("add_button", "add"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("output_table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  if (!file.exists("saved_info.rds")) {
    saveRDS(data.frame(), "saved_info.rds")
  }

  info <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 1000, session = session, filePath = "saved_info.rds", readRDS)

  observeEvent(input$add_button, {

    new_name <- input$input_name
    new_count <- input$input_count

    if (new_name != "" && new_count != "") {
      new_data <- data.frame(name = new_name, count = new_count, select = as.character(selectInput(paste0("pick_", new_name), label = "", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))))
      saveRDS(rbind(info(), new_data), "saved_info.rds")
    }
  })

  output$output_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(info(),
      escape = FALSE,
      selection = 'none')
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

While I can insert the pickerInput via `as.character(selectInput(...))`, but i check the `.rds`, i found that the selectInputs is in html language`"<div class=\"form-group shiny-input-container\">\n  <label class=\"control-label shiny-label-null\" for=\"pick_56456\" id=\"pick_56456-label\"></label>\n  <div>\n    <select id=\"pick_56456\" class=\"shiny-input-select\"><option value=\"A\" selected>A</option>\n<option value=\"B\">B</option>\n<option value=\"C\">C</option></select>\n    <script type=\"application/json\" data-for=\"pick_56456\" data-nonempty=\"\">{\"plugins\":[\"selectize-plugin-a11y\"]}</script>\n  </div>\n</div>"`

I want the option content A or B or C to be saved

And other users can see the option when they open myapp on their own PC

Comment: There's no persistent data storage on shinyapps - you can read an .rds but you can't write a new version of it. See https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/persistent-data-storage/ for various techniques to store data.

Comment: MySQL or others are really good, but I always try for the lowest cost implementation. The way I save `.rds`, overwrite `.rds`, read `.rds` and so on in a loop does work on shinyapps.io. I verified it.

Comment: Ok but if someone else visits the app they may not get the same version of the `.rds`

Comment: I solved the problem with a different version by using `reactiveFileReader()`